# Implementing roles with custom storage provider for Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, adfs, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-roles

Recently, I was able to successfully implement authentication (SSO with ADFS using WS-Federation) for an app. Now, I am trying to understand and get authorization working, so this question may be unclear.

I'm using [this topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-3.0) to implement roles with custom storage provider for Identity without entity framework.

I've got custom `User` and `Role` models set up, along with the custom `UserStore` and `RoleStore` that implement the appropriate interfaces. There's also tables for roles ready to be used.

I run into issues when trying to access either an `[Authorized]` or `[Authorized(Roles = "RoleName")]`. As expected, the actions require me to authenticate with ADFS, but when I submit correct credentials the login loops a few times and displays the ADFS error page. This problem with ADFS is not present without the role implementation. `UserStore` and `RoleStore` does not implement code yet, but the app never tries uses any of their methods.

I tried implementing different options in `Startup.cs`, some of which I have commented out, and reordering services. Inserting dummy code into the `RoleStore` didn't help either. Basically, I just want to be able to add [role checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-3.0) from custom storage using Identity. I can get the username of the user at any time after they log in to find their role.

`Startup.cs ConfigureServices` method is where it's most unclear for me, and probably the most likely place where something is set up incorrectly.

Startup.cs ConfigureServices():

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add identity types
    services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
        //.AddUserManager<UserManager<User>>() // some other settings I've tried ...
        //.AddRoleManager<RoleManager<Role>>()
        //.AddUserStore<UserStore>()
        //.AddRoleStore<RoleStore>()
        //.AddRoles<Role>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    // Identity Services
    services.AddTransient<IUserStore<User>, UserStore>();
    services.AddTransient<IRoleStore<Role>, RoleStore>();
    //for SQL connection, I'll be using a different one (not the one from the link to topic)

    //dependency injection
    services.AddScoped<ISomeService, SomeService>();

    services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
    {
        // authentication options...
    })
    .AddWsFederation(options =>
    {
        // wsfed options...
    })
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "NameOfCookie";
        //options.LoginPath = "/Access/Login"; //app function the same without this
        options.LogoutPath = "/Access/Logout";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Access/AccessDenied";
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    });

    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of doing this is to add a [custom attribute store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/cloudpfe/how-to-create-a-custom-attribute-store-for-active-directory-federation-services-3-0) to ADFS.

Then the roles etc. that you require from the custom attribute store can be configured as claims.